# Regular Expression not grouping

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Need help with this regex

```
ABC          130  zlis               02-03/12 N180 Grouping req
A B Csd       130  pain          02/12 I80 alias

(\w+\s{0,3})(\d+)
```

The regex does not seem to group as I need it to.

Desired Output, brackests are the groups im trying to detect.

(A B Csd)      (130)  (pain)          (02/12) (I80) (alias)

Comment: It's `\d+`, not `\+d`...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

`([a-z ]+?)\s+(\d+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([\d-\/]+)\s+([\w ]+)`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/skKHel/2)

**Explanation:**

- `([a-z ]+?)` - match 1+ occurrences(as few as possible) of a letter or a space and capture it as Group1
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace character
- `(\d+)` - match 1+ occurrences of digits and capture as Group2
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace character
- `([a-z]+)` - match 1+ occurrences of a letter and Capture as Group 3
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace character
- `([\d-\/]+)` - match 1+ occurrences of a digit or `-` or `/` and capture it as Group4
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace character
- `([\w ]+)` - match 1+ occurrences of a word-character or a space and capture as Group5

Note that I have used the `g`, `i`, `m` flags for Global matches, Case-insensitive and Multiline respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: The site you recommended, does it help with regex in vba?

Comment: No, it doesn't have any flavor for VBA. But the regex I provided will work in VBA too.

Comment: @RyanGomes At regex101, choose the JavaScript regex engine, it is just the same as the one used in VBA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks you, will use that